# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for $('#cropbox').Jcrop({

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

When i am using Cropping functionality in Spree eCommerce using gem "spree_image_cropper" ([Github link](https://github.com/pero-ict-solutions/spree_image_cropper))

It gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in crop.html.erb for $('#cropbox').Jcrop({.

How can I fix this? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The Jcrop library is not being loaded correctly. There could be any number of reasons for this, such as an error elsewhere in your code to the js file path being wrong. Check the console and see if there's any errors shown there.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, console it's show me "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error. and When i click on error it's show "$('#cropbox').Jcrop({" and line number of file.

Answer (score 2):

**Steps to Use Spree Image Cropper.**

Step 1 ) Download Code From below link.

```
https://github.com/pero-ict-solutions/spree_image_cropper
```

Step 2 ) Downloaded code put in home dir with unzip file.

```
/home/PC-Name/spree_image_cropper/lib/generators/spree_image_cropper/
```

Step 3) Open “install_generator.rb” file.

```
Replace this code with respectively method.

  def add_javascripts 
    append_file 'vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/all.js', "//= require               spree/backend/spree_image_cropper\n" 
  end 

  def add_stylesheets 
    inject_into_file 'vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/all.css', " *= require spree/backend/spree_image_cropper\n", before: /\*\//, verbose: true 
  end
```

Step 4) Add gem "spree_image_cropper" in gem file with local url.

For Example

```
gem "spree_image_cropper", :path => "/home/pc-name/spree_image_cropper"
```

Step 5)  bundle install

Step 6)  bundle exec rails generate spree_image_cropper:install

Answer (score 0):

This extension installer is not compatible with the version of spree you are using.

To fix just add this line into your `vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/all.js`:

`//= require spree/backend/spree_image_cropper`

and this one into your `vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/all.css`:

`*= require spree/backend/spree_image_cropper`

Comment: I also perform stem you have given. but still problem, because when gem install at that time path set.

I have fixed issue. Using gem run local with changing path in spree_image_cropper/lib/generators/spree_image_cropper/install_generator.rb.